# Need to remove a P Class (cant remove it in code)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to remove the contents of

```
<p class="print_pdf">
```

from a single page on my site.

I cant use CSS, and I cant edit the index file to remove it as its XML and an element that loads on every page of our catalog site.

I've tried for example

```
$( "p.print_pdf" ).replaceWith( "" );
```

Without any luck

[Link to the page in question - Haper College Catalog](https://www.harpercollege.edu/catalog/index.php)

Comment: Remove the *class* of `p` *and its contents*…!?

Comment: Have you tried anything which didn't work out as you'd hoped…?

Comment: Basically, all the code you see above needs to vanish or become - <p class="print_pdf"></p>

Comment: The question is a bit vague - I mean technically the answer could be *open your index page, delete that chunk of code and upload it* ...

Comment: And even if we give you code using simple [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) [APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) to remove the element, we have no idea if that might have unintended side effects on your page (e.g. `p.print_pdf` is not unique on the page)…

Comment: Its an XML script that loads dynamically on every page. I only need to exclude it post rendering on the index.

Comment: Well if it's *post-rendering* that's pretty much PHP out of the equation then...

Comment: Define "without any luck". Seems to work just fine when testing it on your page. Though I have no idea what element it's removing to begin with, since I can't see the link to the PDF anywhere.

Comment: It may help in asking (or re-writing) this question if you have correct terminology.  `p` is not a "class", it is a "tag" — as in [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) -- while `print_pdf` *is* a class.

Comment: You can remove (or detach) the element via `$('p.print_pdf').remove();` An easily viewable element you can try this on is the link to "Programs of Study"... enter this in your browser console: `$('a[href*="programs/index"]').detach()`

Comment: I never really got a working answer but this was my solution - lockedowndesign.com/301-redirect-pdf-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

You're printing a page and you want to remove the print icon when printing, right?

So, you can use CSS for that:

```
@media print
{    
    .print_pdf, .print_pdf *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope i need to remove <p class="print_pdf"> and its contents. Ironically this has nothing to do with printing. Also no I cant use 'display:none'

Comment: @Wesley Why not? What other restrictions do you have?

Comment: Because when I hide it with CSS. Its still coming up as a broken link on this one page. I cant change the script because its dynamic for every page in our catalog website and the index page is the only one without a PDF.

Comment: But you HAVE to change the script. You cannot run javascript in a pdf page

Comment: I never really got a working answer but this was my solution - https://www.lockedowndesign.com/301-redirect-pdf-wordpress/